# I get SEC_ERROR_BAD_DER in Firefox when visiting mozilla sites

Tags: firefox

I am not sure if this is the right place but ... I get SEC_ERROR_BAD_DER in Firefox when visiting Mozilla sites.

This is continuing over an 6 months now and i was waiting to be fixed, i guess it's not from the Firefox version, maybe it is from some configuration.

I have tried to reinstall the browser, run it in clean mode and nothing helps. Chrome do not have same issue with Mozilla sites

Comment: Could you post more about the error? Specifically the text you see in the console. What OS are you running on?

Comment: I'm on windows 8.1. This is what i see in the browser:

"An error occurred during a connection to addons.cdn.mozilla.net. security library: improperly formatted DER-encoded message. Error code: SEC_ERROR_BAD_DER

    The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
    Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem."

there is nothing in console. I have seen that if i restart Windows in safe mode then everything is working fine

Comment: This might be one to post to Mozilla's bug report center.

Comment: Check this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1088140